# How do I escape a single quote&double quote in SQL Server?

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm using SQL2000.
How can i escape single quote&double quote into query without get SQLi?

```
PHP:
$Username = "s'ql'fp".'"ffo"t';

SQL:
$Query = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password) VALUES (".$Username.", '432432')";
mssql_query($Query);
```

Sorry for my bad english :S

Answer (score 1):

You must enclose string constants in single quotes and double all single quotes within them in SQL:

```
PHP:
$Username = "s'ql'fp".'"ffo"t'";

SQL:
$Query = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password) VALUES ('"
          . str_replace("'", "''", $Username),
          . "', '432432')";
mssql_query($Query);
```

`str_replace("'", "''", $Username)` will be `"s''ql''fp".''"ffo"t''"`, i. e. all single quotes doubled. This does not change your `$Username` variable, but just the string used as SQL statement.

Probably, you would do that for the password as well (if it is not a string you know does not contain quotes, as is the case for the literal password you use here).

Comment: I can't using this because i need to allow using in this characters in login.

Comment: @Yoshimitso Yes, the single quotes can be in the user name. But as you enclose string literals in single quotes in SQL, you need to double them within strings.

Answer (score -2):

mysqli_real_escape_string() on the inserted data should do the trick.

You should also put your varchar()s in brackets, escaping won't help if you insert VALUES (SOME STRING) this works mainly with integers.

Comment: Can i using this function for secure query in SQL server? it's same escaping ?

Comment: It will help with security for sure.